# PLSQL Table not created within a stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic, plsql

I have created a procedure that will basically take in 3 parameters to drop & re-create tables and indexes. It will start by checking if there is a table existing, if so then it will drop it and proceed. If not, then it will automatically proceed to create the table and index. Below is the my procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PROCEDURE PROC_RFRSH (TBL_NME IN VARCHAR2, TABLE_QRY IN CLOB, CRT_INDX IN CLOB)
IS 
-- VARIABLE TO BE USED TO CHECK IF TABLE/INDEX EXISTS 
COUNT_TABLE NUMBER; 
DRP_TBL VARCHAR2(4000); 

BEGIN
-- CHECK IF TABLE EXISTS 
SELECT COUNT(*) 
INTO COUNT_TABLE
FROM USER_TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = TBL_NME; -- AGAINST THE PASSED IN TABLE NAME 

-- IF TABLE EXISTS, 
IF COUNT_TABLE > 0 THEN 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('THE FOLLOWING TABLE: ' || TBL_NME || ' EXISTS!');
-- DROP TABLE CASCADE CONSTRAINTS 
DRP_TBL := 'DROP TABLE ' || TBL_NME || ' CASCADE CONSTRAINTS'; 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE DRP_TBL; 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TABLE HAS BEEN DROPPED!');
END IF; 

-- CREATE TABLE 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE TABLE_QRY; 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TBL_NME || ' HAS BEEN CREATED');

-- CREATE INDEX 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CRT_INDX;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('INDEX HAS BEEN CREATED');

EXCEPTION 
    WHEN OTHERS THEN 
        NULL;
END;    -- PROCEDURE ENDS HERE 
/
```

And here is the values I am sending to the procedure:

```
DECLARE 
TBL_NME VARCHAR2(30)    := 'CUS_TBL';
TABLE_QRY CLOB          := 'CREATE TABLE CUS_TBL
                            ( customer_id number(10) NOT NULL,
                              customer_name varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
                              city varchar2(50)
                            );'; 
INDX_NME VARCHAR2(30)   := 'CUS_INDX'; 
COL_NME VARCHAR2(55)    := 'customer_id '; 
CRT_INDX CLOB           := 'CREATE INDEX ' || INDX_NME || ' ON CUS_TBL(' || COL_NME || ')';

BEGIN     
PROC_RFRSH(TBL_NME, TABLE_QRY, CRT_INDX);
END;
/
```

My problem is that the table I am trying to create is not actually being created by this procedure and I don't understand why. Can you guys help please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Remove the `EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;` and it will tell you why it is failing. I'm guessing that will show ORA-00911 because your `create table` statement should not have a semicolon at the end, but there could be something else wrong too.

Comment: I did and I received this error "ORA-00922: missing or invalid option"

Comment: Actually, you're right. I just removed the semi-colon and now it is working! Thank you.

Comment: It seems a bit trusting to assume that `TABLE_QRY` is always going to be a DDL statement that creates table `TBL_NME`. What it it creates a different table, or truncates all tables, or grants privileges to a hacker or something? And as you found out, there might be syntax errors and you will never know.

Comment: To be blunt, why do you want to constantly drop and recreate this table? Just delete the rows in it.

Comment: Look up `TRUNCATE TABLE`. Best of luck.

Comment: I tried `TRUNCATE TABLE` and it worked just fine. But as a requirement for a project I'm working on I have to drop & recreate every night.

Comment: Your project requirements are badly formed. You have a requirement (*'we need to start with a empty table each day'*) defined as a solution (*'we need to drop and recreate the table each day'*) . The solution-as-requirement is a common anti-pattern. It leads to suboptimal implementations and unforeseen side-effects. Maybe you don't feel confident having this discussion with the requirements setter. Maybe it doesn't matter (say if this is a school assignment). But the main teaching is that as a developer you should challenge bad requirements.